# How can i update my object boolean value to true and false?

Tags: javascript, react-native

> Here is my data

```
data: [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: 'Apparel',
    overall_rtng: '1',
    price_rtng: '2',
    clean_rtng: '3',
    qlty_rtng: '4',
    contPrsn: 'Mr. Shezad Ali, +92-313-0226224',
    addrs: 'H # 331/A, Block-C, Gulshan-E-Ravi,Lahore',
    img: coffe,
    islike: false,
    cid: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    overall_rtng: '5',
    price_rtng: '6',
    clean_rtng: '7',
    qlty_rtng: '8',
    name: 'Hot Choclate',
    contPrsn: 'Mr. Shezad Ali, +92-313-0226224',
    addrs: 'H # 331/A, Block-C, Gulshan-E-Ravi,Lahore',
    img: coffe,
    islike: false,
    cid: 2,
  }
]
```

> Here is my render function of flatlist

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.toogleLike(item.cid)}>
  <MaterialIcons
    name="favorite"
    size={25}
    color={item.islike ? 'red' : 'black'}
    style={{alignSelf: 'center'}}
  />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

> here is toggle Like function

```
toogleLike = (id) => {
  // console.log(this.state.data);

  const res = this.state.data.map((item) => {
    if (item.cid === id) {
      return {
        ...item,
        islike: true,
      };
    }
  });
  console.log(res);
  this.setState({data: res});
};
```

> Here is my result

```
[
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  {
    "addrs": "H # 331/A, Block-C, Gulshan-E-Ravi,Lahore",
    "cid": 5,
    "clean_rtng": "4",
    "contPrsn": "Mr. Shezad Ali, +92-313-0226224",
    "id": 4,
    "img": 9,
    "islike": true,
    "name": "Cold Coffee",
    "overall_rtng": "3",
    "price_rtng": "2",
    "qlty_rtng": "5"
  }
]
```

Comment: What do you return if `item.cid !== id`?

Comment: what should i return?

Comment: If the id doesn't match you don't want to change anything, so you should return the unchanged item. A common patter is to use a guard clause. `if (item.cid !== id) return item` then write your code that makes changes if the id does match after this line. You could also just use `else { return item }` (using the current if) depending on the style you prefer.

Comment: To understand what's going wrong her you have to know what [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) does.`map` maps each item to a new value, so if you don't return anything the current element will be mapped to `undefined`, since that is the return value of functions without `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because your map function is wrong.

it should be

```
toogleLike = (id) => { 
  const res = this.state.data.map((item) => {
    if (item.cid === id) {
      return {
        ...item,
        islike: true,
      };
    }
    return item;
  }); 
  this.setState({data: res});
};
```